# What does ($a,$b,$c) = @array mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, syntax

I'd google it if I could but honestly I don't know what to search for (an inherent problem with symbol-heavy languages)!

```
($aSvnRemote, $aSvnLocal, $aSvnRef, $aSvnOptions) = @{$aSvnPair};
```

My guess is that `$aSvnPair` is an array of 4 values (in which case it's a very poorly named variable!) and this is just splitting it into specific variable identities...?

Comment: `@arr` or `@{$ref}`, doesn't matter to "what happens" otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's nothing more than a list assignment. The first value of the RHS is assigned to the first var on the LHS, and so on. That means

```
($aSvnRemote, $aSvnLocal, $aSvnRef, $aSvnOptions) = @{$aSvnPair};
```

is the same as

```
$aSvnRemote  = $aSvnPair->[0];
$aSvnLocal   = $aSvnPair->[1];
$aSvnRef     = $aSvnPair->[2];
$aSvnOptions = $aSvnPair->[3];
```

Comment: which does *not* necessitate `@$aSvnPair` having four elements; it could have more (which will be ignored) or less (setting some of the LHS variables to undef).

Comment: @ysth, Indeed, just like the second snippet does.

Comment: Just note for question starter: naming `$aSvnPair` is really strange. So probably it is hashref, not arrayref. In this case second snippet is not equal and will fail. Just to note about "pair" word in variable name...

Comment: @PSIAlt, That's not true. Both snippets will throw an exception if given a hash ref. The very same error (`Not an ARRAY reference`), no less.

Comment: O, really, my bad. How to cast hashref into array then?

Comment: There are no cast in Perl. You *dereference* using "%".

Answer (score 6):

The variable `$aSvnPair` is a reference to an array. Adding the `@` sigil causes the array to be referenced. In this example, the array is unpacked and it's elements are assigned to the variables on the right.

Here is an example of what is happening:

```
$aSvnPair= [ qw(foo bar baz xyxxy) ];

($aSvnRemote, $aSvnLocal, $aSvnRef, $aSvnOptions) = @{$aSvnPair};
```

After this operation, you get the following:

```
$aSvnRemote  = "foo";
$aSvnLocal   = "bar";
$aSvnRef     = "baz";
$aSvnOptions = "xyxxy";
```

Answer (score 1):

`$aSvnPair` should be a *reference to an array* so `@{$aSvnPair}` dereferences it. (A "reference" is the Perl equivalent of a pointer.)

The statement then assigns the values of this array to the four variables on the left-hand side, in order.

See this tutorial for some examples: [Dereferencing in perl](http://www.perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html)